# AWS Lambda Java/Kotlin Send Message to SQS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, kotlin, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have been using Kotlin to create an AWS Lambda function. The function works well but seems unable to send an SQS message to a FIFO queue. I receive the folowing message in Cloudwatch:

```
REPORT RequestId: 9119da93-e775-11e7-820a-5bbbb7403f93  Duration: 10010.16 ms   Billed Duration: 10000 ms Memory Size: 128 MB   Max Memory Used: 54 MB  

2017-12-23T00:09:49.483Z 9119da93-e775-11e7-820a-5bbbb7403f93 Task timed out after 10.01 seconds
```

I have rewritten my code to use Node JS and it executes fine and I have the relevant permissions setup for the lambda function, tested via the console permissions simulator for good measure, to put messages on the specified queue. Due to the fact it works completely fine in Node then I have to assume I have something wrong in my Java/Kotlin version.

If I remove the below code the function reaches the end and returns ok. I have tried a variety of methods to create the client (including the deprecated options) and `EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider` and `DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain`.

I have also tried increasing the timeout to 20 seconds however this made no difference either.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

```
val sqs = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2)
                .withCredentials(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
                .build()

val sendMessageRequest = SendMessageRequest()
                .withMessageDeduplicationId("deduplicationId")
                .withMessageGroupId("test")
                .withQueueUrl("https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/00000000/test.fifo")
                .withMessageBody("test")

val sendResult = sqs.sendMessage(sendMessageRequest)
```

Update: this is the response code back to Lambda. This code seems to work without the call to SQS. I have tried adding a try/catch to the `sendMessage()` method and the Lambda still times out.

```
    val responseBody = JsonObject()
    responseBody.addProperty("message", "ok")

    val headerJson = JsonObject()
    headerJson.addProperty("test", "test")

    val responseJson = JsonObject()
    responseJson.addProperty("statusCode", 200)
    responseJson.add("headers", headerJson)
    responseJson.addProperty("body", responseBody.toString())

    val writer = OutputStreamWriter(output, "UTF-8")
    writer.write(responseJson.toString())
    writer.close()
```

Comment: Usually, lambda times out when there is an unhandled error and callback wasn't called.  Is possible that some parameters are wrong/missing and lambda errors out and cloudwatch doesn't log it.

Comment: Is there any way to capture these errors? Try catch with some logging?

Comment: Not familiar with Kotlin but maybe try catch around the lambda.  Is there aws sqs docs for kotlin or java docs.  sendMessage does throw exceptions.  With Kotlin do you have to do callback when exiting lambda function?

Comment: I added the response code although that executes ok when the SQS code is commented out. I tried the try/catch but it still times out.

Comment: Can you check sqs logs in cloudwatch maybe it shows an error there.

Comment: Thanks Yan. The logs show no activity. I created a new SQS Queue just in case and there is no activity. I guess this shows that the Java function is not reaching SQS in anyway and it is just timing out. I will create a new Java function tomorrow and make it open source so others can have a play with it and see what results they get.

Comment: Sounds good.   Post back the link. I would like to try java lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

Check the security groups for outbound and inbound on port 80 and 443 for the sqs endpoint.  You mention node.js is working - but there may be a difference in the configuration.